# creating regular expressions from given language

Tags: automata, regular-language, regular-expressions

The first question is $L_1 = \{w \in \{a,b,c\}^∗ \mid \text{$w$ ends with $ca$}\}$

I started by creating a DFA for that for better understanding and then making a regular expression.

[image: The DFA I've created]

and the regular expression for this is (NOTE:'*' = iteration ): $[(a+b)^*c(a+b)a]$
before I created the DFA my intuition was $(a+b+c)^*ca$

The second question is $L_2 = \{w \in \{a,b,c\}^∗ \mid \text{$w$  doesn't contain $cba$}\}$

[image: Again, the DFA is]

And the regular expression is: $[(a+b)^*(c^*a)(b^*c)a(a+b+c)^*]$

SOLVED:
For the first question - instead of creating DFA I've made NFA

[NFA HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7c8q.jpg)

And the regular expression for this is: (a+b+c)* ca

For the second question, I've used the blocking method. The regular expression is: (b+a)* (cr)*
r = (bb+a)(b+a)* + b + ε

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Yes, It went wrong with the *

Comment: That first diagram has does not show transition on input `c` from state $q_1$.  It also has two transitions on input `a` from state $q_1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question - instead of creating DFA I've made NFA

[NFA HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rdMt4.jpg)

And the regular expression for this is: (a+b+c)* ca

For the second question, I've used the blocking method. The regular expression is: (b+a)* (cr)*
r = (bb+a)(b+a)* + b + ε